# Need a script to find files modified in the last three days and exclude all backup folders

Tags: command-line, find

I'm trying to set a script to let me know what WordPress files have been modified in the last 3 days, but I get a huge list of every site's backups when I just run:

```
find /var/websites -mtime -1
```

How do I exclude all directories with the word `backup` in them? An example of a path that I'd like to exclude is `/var/websites/com.site1/backup` and all of its subdirectories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find` in this way:

```
find /var/websites -type f -mtime -3 -not -path '*/backup/*'
```

`-not -path '*/backup/*'` will cause `find` to ignore the files that have `/backup/` in their path. The trailing `/` in `/backup/` is to ensure that this will only consider `backup` as directory names.

Also note that to get precise result regarding time you should use `-mmin` instead of `-mtime`. Check `man find` to get more idea on this.

Comment: Also note that to get best results you should read `man find` over and over.

Comment: @waltinator: Have i put anything that could fail? if so could you please point to it..

Comment: No, but having the questioner learn about `find` (and `man`) is, IMHO, a Good Thing. The "you" I used referred to the original poster.